# Java ImageIO Mean Filter

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am currently trying to write a program in which applies a mean filter by user input determining the neighbourhood size and filetype. My program complies and runs but the outputted image that I get is nothing close to what was put in. I am not sure if it the reading in that is throwing it off or the output, or maybe even the math but my images end up being noting but a big salt and pepper image. Here is my code, as for now I am applying the 3x3 mean filter just to get it running properly

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));

//get dimensions
maxHeight = img.getHeight();
maxWidth = img.getWidth();

//create 2D Array for new picture
int pictureFile[][] = new int [maxHeight][maxWidth];
for( int i = 0; i < maxHeight; i++ ){
    for( int j = 0; j < maxWidth; j++ ){
        pictureFile[i][j] = img.getRGB( j, i );
    }
}

//Apply Mean Filter
for (int v=1; v<=maxHeight-2; v++) {
    for (int u=1; u<=maxWidth-2; u++) {
        //compute filter result for position (u,v)

        int sum = 0;
        for (int j=-1; j<=1; j++) {
            for (int i=-1; i<=1; i++) {
                int p = pictureFile[u+i][v+j];
                sum = sum + p;

            }
        }

        int q = (int) (sum / 9);
        pictureFile[u][v] = q;
    }
}

//Turn the 2D array back into an image
BufferedImage theImage = new BufferedImage(
    maxHeight, 
    maxWidth, 
    BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
int value;
for(int y = 0; y<maxHeight; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x<maxWidth; x++){

        value = pictureFile[y][x] ;
        theImage.setRGB(x, y, value);
    }
}

File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
ImageIO.write(theImage, "png", outputfile);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) For an SSCCE dealing with images, hot-link to one or generate it in code.  3) Linking to a couple of small 'original/transformed/expected' images would be immensely helpful. 4) Did you have a question?  If so, now would be a good time to ask it.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to apply arithmetic operations to ARGB values packed into `int`s, as returned by `getRGB()`.

Since you want your output to be grayscale, you need to convert values returned by `getRGB()` to grayscale, apply your filter to that grayscale values and then convert them back to ARGB for passing them to `setRGB()`.

**See also:**

- [Luminance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance_%28relative%29)
- [Bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)